# .htaccess rewrite to keep subdirectory as the root of the website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have server that contains different folders for different websites:

```
-- root
    --- automation
    --- thecorporation
-- .htaccess
```

its URL looks like this:

```
http://example.com:3333
```

I need to rewite the URL so when the user visits one of the pages like: `http://example.com:3333/automation` the `automation` folder would become the root, because now if a menu is clicked to access: `http://example.com:3333/automation/contact` php looks for files on the server but these sites are single page websites:

> File does not exist: /var/www/html/automation/contact, referer:
>   `http://example.com:3333/automation`

I really suck at regex and htaccess I would really appreciate some help. What I have tried so far was, but it does not work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^automation/?$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: While htaccess can do this, it's a LOT easier to do this within the Apache configuration itself

Comment: should I set up Virtual Hosts?

Comment: I don't know that you have to go that far for one site, but you can easily tell it that `automation` is the root within your `<Directory>` directive

Comment: Where is `index.php` located?